# react-native-router-flux does not trigger life-cycle hooks

Tags: react-native

Using:
- react-native-router-flux v3.26.1
- react-native v0.26.1

I have some simple scene components that are set up as such:

```
<Router>
  <Scene key="root">
    <Scene key="tabbar" tabs={true}
            rightButtonImage={require('./img/settings-icon-small.png')}
            onRight={Actions.settings}
            >
        <Scene key="tab2" icon={TabIcon} title="Component 1">
            <Scene key="component1" component={Component1} title="Title 1" />
        </Scene>
        <Scene key="tab3" icon={TabIcon} initial={true} style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'transparent'}} title="Component 2">
            <Scene key="component2" component={Component2} title="Title 2" />
        </Scene>
        <Scene key="tab1" icon={TabIcon} title="Component 3">
            <Scene key="component3" component={Component3} title="Title 3" />
        </Scene>
    </Scene>
    <Scene key="settings" title="Settings" component={Settings} />
  </Scene>
</Router>
```

The tab components are supposed to use a setting from AsyncStorage to decide what content to show.

The "settings" component does a simple action, allows a user to set an option that is saved in AsyncStorage. This is confirmed as working, by setting, then reloading the app and checking the saved value.

Navigating to the Settings component is achieved by a link in top right of Navigation Bar, and then returning to the main three tabbed components is done by simply using the Navigation Bar "back" button behavior.

### Current trials and errors:

#### Pass as a prop from AppRoot to Scene

- AppRoot is where the  is set up, render() has above code snippet
- works great on initial load, but no subsequent life-cycle events are triggered so the AppRoot is never triggered to re-load the AsyncStorage value, and thus never generates a new prop value to pass down to Scene components.

#### Attempting to read the AsyncStorage from the independent components.

- works great on initial load, but no subsequent life-cycle events are triggered so the components never know when to look again.

How should I accomplish this?
Am I doing something wrong in the implementation?
Am I making a wrong assumption of how RNRF works?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone stumbling in here, one way I've discovered to accomplish this so far is with a vanilla Flux loop to keep the mounted components up to date. To that end, I'm sure any varietal of that will work fine (redux etc).

I was experimenting to see if somehow the click actions in RNFR would actually trigger the regular react life-cycle events, but I guess that doesn't happen.

Any further insight from someone who knows more than me, please provide! :-)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?